# Write Twitter data to s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

i am trying to write my streamed data(json format) to s3 bucket. i am using below code but not able to write. No error while executing the below code. but no json files in s3

```
class TweetsListener( StreamListener):

    def __init__(self,path):
        self.path = path

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
            s3.put_object(Bucket='bucket',Body=data.encode('UTF-8'),Key='/A/'+self.path+'/test.json')
            return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print("Error on_data: %s" % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not able to write`? What error (or unexpected result) do you get?

Comment: The runaway red highlighting in the question is pointing to your first problem, which is unrelated to S3.  This code won't run until you fix the missing `'`.

Comment: No error while executing the above code. but no json files in s3

Comment: Do your directories already exist in S3? Try removing the leading `/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you are trying to use `put_object` action on boto3's [S3 Service Resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#service-resource) instead of the [S3 Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object).
The Service Resource doesn't have a `put_object` method.

Also, you should remove the leading `/` in the Key, and make sure that your bucket is already created.